# Fixed Width Flat File & Special Characters

Tags: c#, serialization

In my project; I need to query our database, and then use the result set to generate a fixed width flat file.  I'm using a solution based off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293884/custom-serialization-of-an-object-in-net) question.  All is well and good for 99% of the records, but I am running into one situation that's causing issues:

In the event of "special characters", like ® or ™; it ends up skewing the length of the column when writing to a text file.  When I check the results, I get Â® in the event of the ® symbol, and â„¢ in the event of ™.

I'd like to keep the garbled characters in the final result (for now), cause it'll get picked up later in the validation/sanitation process.  (i.e. in the case of a size like '5½'; I don't want to simply drop the ½ cause then it'll look like '5')

Is there a way to get the actual length of what those special characters will get serialized to so I can take that into account?

**EDIT**
Here's the code that does the text writing:

```
using (var fileStream = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
            {
                foreach (
                    var fileRecord in recordTypes.Select(record => record.RetrieveForImport(startDate, endDate)).SelectMany(records => records))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        fileStream.WriteLine(fileRecord.Serialize());
                    }
                    catch (MySerializationException ex)
                    {
                        LogSerializationError(fileRecord, ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

And I'm using TextPad to verify the results afterwards.

Comment: Are you reading it is `byte[]` or `char[]`. Also, what encoding?

Comment: It doesn't look like any encoding is explicitly defined; so whatever the default would be.  I'm not sure what you mean by reading it in; the data comes back from the database as a DataTable, and I write via a StreamWriter.

Comment: Show us how you are creating the StreamWriter - you are probably using the default UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Also what are you using to view the file?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, I updated my question with the requested info.